# How to measure a perfomance of SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, database-tuning, performance, performance-testing, query-performance

I have the task to improve the performance of a SQL Server 2012 database (one of 4 in an instance) by 60% confirmed by corresponding statistics.

So, I need to measure "performance" of the RDBMS database before performance tuning and optimization and after.

Which metrics are better suited for this?

Trying to answer the obvious questions ahead ...

I/O (hardware) bottlenecks are absent since the SQL Server runs on a virtual rack having plenty of physical resources under it.

The database is used by approx. 60 users (mostly 8 hours a day) with widely varying load (per sec).

This is a company management task, so the results of this task should be easy to grasp.

UPDATE:
[the corresponding my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812530/how-to-measure-a-performance-of-a-sql-server-database) was answered in StackOverflow.com by @[Martin von Wittich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100614/martin-von-wittich) and, then, deleted by moderator/community:

> Run different kinds of queries (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) in a loop
>   (e.g. 1000 times), then divide the runtime by the amount of loop
>   iterations. Now you now how long a single query of that type takes.
>
> Then do whatever you want to do to improve the performance, and
>   compare the results.

Quite good for me. Also I do not see why it was deleted in SO with the reason: "This question does not appear to be about programming" and closed in this site with: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."

Comment: How do you know there are no hardware bottlenecks if you haven't measured the performance yet?

Comment: How have you decided that I had not measured the performance yet? I've measured a lot of metrics, the question is about one simple and illustrative one for non-specialists

Comment: What aspects of database performance matter to the business? Is there a business-critical application currently suffering from poor response times from the database? If so, monitoring the response times the application gets from the database using whatever instrumentation is available for the app's programming language or framework might be useful. As is, I don't think there is enough information in the question for anyone here to assess what should be monitored.

Comment: @Fulproof you say you have measured "a lot of metrics", so what is it that you want to measure, as outlined in your question.

Comment: What indications dictate the need for a "task to improve the performance of a SQL Server 2012 database". If you provide this information the question would provide a more narrow answer. There are baseline metrics that you can capture for overall health, but if you have specific performance issue then it narrows down the amount of information needed for your metrics.

Comment: @ShawnMelton, the indication is that nobody systematically had been doing it before in a long term. The main known to me problem is that when an application performance using a database slows down to a halt, it is not clear where and what to investigate. The Windows domain system administrators are a few thousands km away and there were no DBAs and sysadmins specifically monitoring SQL Servers as well as specialists having access to SQL Servers and to domain administration (application servers) are different people not collaborating much between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I/O (hardware) bottlenecks are absent since the SQL Server runs on a virtual rack having 
>   plenty of physical resources under it.

Let's get this straight:

- Most virtualization is pathetic - not even low, pathetic - on the IO side.
- "having plenty" means nothing unless you qantify there is no IO problem.

At the end, come up with the metcis you need to measure, and find the bottlenexks. But starting with "virtual rack has no IO issues" will give you smiles from most people using virtualization.